# Pre populate core data with only one Managed Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I need to pre populate my core data base with only one Managed Object.

Currently i'm checking on AppDelegate if it's the fisrt time that the app runs, and then a add the object, like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

BOOL firstTime = [defaults boolForKey:@"firstTime"];

if (firstTime) {
    [dataManager insertManagedObject:myManagedObect];

    [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"firstTime"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

`insertManagedObject` method checks if the managedObject is already in the data base.

It's working fine, but i'm afraid in future app updates this could cause me some kind of trouble, mainly if i change my data model and add a new data model version.

What's the best approach to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your question is not clear to me...

Comment: I just need to add one entry as default data on my model. I did that like i showed above, but i want to know if this approach won't cause troubles in future updates and if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Why don't you execute a fetch request a see if the store already contains that managed object? e..g setting a specific identifier for that managed object...

Comment: I do that, before insert on store i verify if that objet already exists

Comment: So, you don't need to check/save on user defaults...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why don't you execute a fetch request a see if the store already
>   contains that managed object? e.g setting a specific identifier for
>   that managed object...

Following my comment you could just set up a fetch request against your entity and see if the store already has an instance for it.

This is simple enough to achieve.

If you need to query against a specific object, you could set a property identifier (i.e. a guid) for your entity and use a predicate to see if the object with the specific guid exists or not.

If you share some other details I can give you other suggestions...

Comment: Should i execute this fetch request in my app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: I wont post a separate answer as @flexaddicted's answer pretty much sums it up. Yes just create a NSFetchRequest in appdelegate and check if the object exists.

Comment: @douglasd3 yes, you can. Obviously you need to setup the Core Data stack first.